# breezejs set created at record with server datetime

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I have to save when the record created, and it must from server time.

for example my design :

```
{
Content : newPost,
CreatedBy : uid,
DataId : pk.Id,
Id: breeze.core.getUuid(),
CreatedAt : serverTime
}
```

when i do :

```
manager.addEntity(newItem);
manager.saveChanges();
```

`CreatedAt` or `serverTime` will be filled with `DateTime.Now` from server, not cluent

Answer (score 0):

If you want the server datetime, you will need to update the entities on the server before they are saved.  You should add a `BeforeSaveEntity` or `BeforeSaveEntities` method on your server-side `ContextProvider`, and update the `CreatedAt` property in that method.

There is an example in the [ContextProvider documentation](http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/contextprovider.html#originalvaluesmap).